# Laravel application logged out after oauth url redirect

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I have implemented zoom oauth2 using [league/oauth2-client](http://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/) library.

After authenticating from zoom and returning to the application, it's asking me to login again.

I could not able to understand the issue of why it's getting logged out after coming back.

below is my code:

```php
    public function authorize(Request $request)
    {
        $config = config('services.zoom');

        $provider = new ZoomProvider([
            'clientId'          => $config['client_id'],
            'clientSecret'      => $config['client_secret'],
            'redirectUri'       => url('/connect/zoom'),
            'state' => uuid()
        ]);

        $code = $request->query('code');
        $state = $request->query('state');

        if (empty($code)) {
            // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
            $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();

            // Get the state generated for you and store it to the session.
            session(['oauth2state' => $provider->getState()]);

            return redirect($authUrl);
            // Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
        } else {
            try {
                // Try to get an access token using the authorization code grant.
                $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                    'code' => $code
                ]);

                return redirect('/integration/zoom')->with([
                    'status' => 'OK',
                    'message' => 'Account linked'
                ]);
            } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
                return redirect('/integration/zoom')->with([
                    'status' => 'ERROR',
                    'message' => $e->getMessage()
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using laravel 5.3. Not made session configuration changes in `config/session.php`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by changing the session configuration from `'same_site' => 'strict',` to `'same_site' => 'lax',`